# shiny r selectDate startview = "century"?

Tags: r, shiny, calendar, default-value

I am trying to figure out a way to get the Shiny R selectDate function to open up at it's widest state.  As it stands, it has three options for startview = "____"  which are month year or decade.  For example:

```
dateInput("r_num_years", "Date of Birth", format = "mm-dd-yyyy", startview = "decade" )
```

This gives me the following:
[startview = "decade"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eh3HG.png)

Then by clicking on the top of this popup you get second image
and clicking again you get the third image

I want it to **begin** in the state portrayed in the third image.

I hope there is a workaround for this.  I did look through some of the source code on GitHub, and thought [this](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/blob/476f6d83e28012ce56df9f63ba7430ef760f96c0/srcjs/input_binding_date.js#L42) section of code looked relevant.

This seems like it should be a standard feature, because it obviously has the 'state' or 'mode' already...

Comment: Hi @Jason, to clarify - what you want is to first specify "month-day", then year (and then decade?). Starting with `startview = "month"` wouldnt be sufficient, because you cant specify `year` afterwards?

Comment: no, the opposite.  I want it to start in the century state (bottom image)...

Comment: for me he starts in century state, next i can choose year, then month then day,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startview = "centuries"`, or`startview = 4`.

Shiny `dateInput` uses a bootstrap `datepicker`, you can read more about its options [there](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startview)

```
shinyApp(ui=dateInput("r_num_years", "Date of Birth",format = "mm-dd-yyyy", 
                      startview = "centuries" ),
         server=function(input, output){})
```